# Creating Javascript Object from a textfield and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create a Javascript Object and add property and value that are inputted from a text field, the user will type example:

person=name 
it will create a new object called person with value name

My code: html

```
<p class="console">
    <input type="text" id="caption"/>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
// my object
myObj = {}
$('#caption').keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // get input value
    caption = captionEl.val();    
    var prop = $.trim(caption.substring(3,caption.indexOf("=")));
    var val = $.trim(caption.substring(caption.indexOf("=")+1,caption.length));      
    // set the property ) NOT WORKING
    myObj["'"+prop+"'"]= val;
    alert(myObj["'"+prop+"'"]);
  }
});
```

could you help me please to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myObj = {}
$('#caption').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
    // get input value
    caption = $(this).val();    
    var prop = $.trim(caption.substring(3,caption.indexOf("=")));
    var val = $.trim(caption.substring(caption.indexOf("=")+1,caption.length));      
    // set the property ) NOT WORKING
    myObj[prop]= val;
    alert(myObj[prop]);
    }
});
```

Comment: how could I check if the property exsist? so exmple myObject[person] if I have it or not?

Comment: if (!(prop in myObj)) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt seem that you have captionEL defined, use

```
caption = $("#caption").val();
```

and it should work